# What does "The indices parameter is deprecated and will be removed (assumed True) in 0.17" mean?

Tags: python, python-2.7, machine-learning, kaggle

I'm just starting to learn python and apologise if this is a really basic question/error.

I'm doing the Kaggle Biological Response tutorial. I'm getting this error

> C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\cross_validation.py:65:
>   DeprecationWarning: The indices parameter is deprecated and will be
>   removed (assumed True) in 0.17   stacklevel=1) Results: 0.458614231133

Anyone know what it means? I've Google it to death and can't find the answer.

The script I'm running is:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn import cross_validation
import logloss
import numpy as np

def main():
    #read in  data, parse into training and target sets
    dataset = np.genfromtxt(open('train.csv','r'), delimiter=',', dtype='f8')[1:]
    target = np.array([x[0] for x in dataset])
    train = np.array([x[1:] for x in dataset])

    #In this case we'll use a random forest, but this could be any classifier
    cfr = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100)

    #Simple K-Fold cross validation. 5 folds.
    #(Note: in older scikit-learn versions the "n_folds" argument is named "k".)
    cv = cross_validation.KFold(len(train), n_folds=5, indices=False)

    #iterate through the training and test cross validation segments and
    #run the classifier on each one, aggregating the results into a list
    results = []
    for traincv, testcv in cv:
        probas = cfr.fit(train[traincv], target[traincv]).predict_proba(train[testcv])
        results.append( logloss.llfun(target[testcv], [x[1] for x in probas]) )

    #print out the mean of the cross-validated results
    print "Results: " + str( np.array(results).mean() )
if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

I believe it's calling this:

```
__author__ = 'nickd'
import scipy as sp
def llfun(act, pred):
    epsilon = 1e-15
    pred = sp.maximum(epsilon, pred)
    pred = sp.minimum(1-epsilon, pred)
    ll = sum(act*sp.log(pred) + sp.subtract(1,act)*sp.log(sp.subtract(1,pred)))
    ll = ll * -1.0/len(act)
    return ll
```

Once again, really sorry if this is basic stuff. I genuinely have never did this before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means that where you use the `indices` keyword argument to call `cross_validation.KFold` that future versions will not support it:

```
cv = cross_validation.KFold(len(train), n_folds=5, indices=False)
```

According to the error message you will have the effect of `indices=True` for 0.17. The message states that they will be removing the keyword argument, likely they don't ignore unused keyword arguments, therefore, likely you will get a `TypeError` exception in 0.17 if you continue to try to pass in indices.

Comment: "not sure if you're using 0.17 or if it's warning you that in the future version 0.17 that will be the effect" -> Option 2, it is warning you that it will be the effect in 0.17.  If he was actually using 0.17 he would get a `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'indices'`.

Comment: Ah! That makes sense. Thanks!!

Comment: @user3914041 Technically it's possible that the future version could ignore extra keyword arguments, however based on the wording of the message "will be removed ... in 0.17", I agree with your conclusion that he isn't using 0.17.

Comment: @CrazyCasta You're right, I hadn't thought about that possibility. I tried it with the dev version though, and it raises an error ;).

Answer (score 1):

It means the `indices` parameter is no longer used and will likely be removed in a future release of `sklearn`. The warning is to give you a chance to adjust your code (i.e., don't pass the `indices` parameter) now so your code doesn't break after they remove it in a future update.